# How to build .dbproj without VSTS DB installed?

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, visual-studio-dbpro

Is it possible to build Visual Studio Database Project (.dbproj) on a machine without Visual Studio Team Suite or Team Foundation Build installed?

I've got a "clean" machine running CC.NET and would like to automatically build .dbproj projects using MSBuild. I wonder is it possible to copy required .targets files and some .dll and make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a license to DB Pro (note that Team Developer edition now includes as part of a recent license change), you can install it on a build server without buying an additional license (as long as it is not used interactively there).  This should eliminate the problem you are trying to solve.